# ¿Como unir dos puntos con una gran linea circular en matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hola tengo las dos coordenadas de dos puntos tanto para la latitud y la longitud, deseo unir estos dos puntos con una gran linea circular (como en los mapas).

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib. pyplot as plt

nylon = -158.2
nylat =  20.4


sflon = -58.4
sflat = -62.1

plt.scatter(nylon, nylat, s= 80, marker ='^', c ='green')
plt.scatter(sflon, sflat, s= 80, marker ='s', c ='blue')

plt.xlim(-180,180)
plt.ylim(-90,90)

plt.show()
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero hacer algo parecido a este ejemplo, solo que en matplotlib no encuentro la forma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes probar con interpolate de scipy iterando en varios puntos, te dejo un ejemplo con un conjunto de puntos:

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([75, 0, 25, 100])
x_curvado = np.linspace(1, 4, 300)
a_BSpline = interpolate.make_interp_spline(x, y)
y_curvado = a_BSpline(x_curvado)

plt.plot(x_curvado, y_curvado)
```

Comment: @marumar cuando pongo dos valores me sales este mensaje "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ejemplo_latitudes_interpolate.py", line 8, in <module>
    a_BSpline = interpolate.make_interp_spline(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\Hola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_bsplines.py", line 827, in make_interp_spline
    "match: expected %s, got %s+%s" % (nt-n, nleft, nright))
ValueError: The number of derivatives at boundaries does not match: expected 2, got 0+0"

Comment: ¿ Qué valores intentas poner ? He corrido el código y no me cuentro se error.

Answer (score 1):

acá según entiendo tu pregunta es poder dibujar una circunferencia :

(x1,y1) (x2,y2)

el punto medio esta definido por [(x1+x2)/2 , (y1+y2)/2]

luego ese punto es el centro de tu circunferencia donde el radio es la diferencia entre el centro y uno de los puntos:

```
import matplotlib. pyplot as plt
import math
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

nylon = -158.2
nylat =  20.4

sflon = -58.4
sflat = -62.1

x3= int((nylon+sflon)/2)
y3= int((nylat+sflat)/2)


pt1=plt.scatter(nylon, nylat, s= 80, marker ='^', c ='green')
pt2=plt.scatter(sflon, sflat, s= 80, marker ='s', c ='blue')
plt.scatter(x3, y3, s= 80, marker ='s', c ='red')


pow_1=math.pow((((nylon+sflon)/2)-sflon),2)
pow_2=math.pow((((nylat+sflat)/2)-sflat),2)

dif=pow_1 +pow_2

dist=math.sqrt(dif)

circle1=plt.Circle((x3,y3), dist, color='grey', fill=False)



ax.add_artist(pt1)
ax.add_artist(pt2)
ax.add_artist(circle1)


plt.xlim(-180,180)
plt.ylim(-90,90)

plt.show()
```

se vera así:
[image: ejemplo]